# Android - MaterialDatePicker layout issue

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker

I am using MaterialDatePicker to select dates. I am facing some designing issues with this.[image]

At the top text are overlapping. Below are the style used:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and below is the gradle dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
```

also used the following dependency as replacement, but still same problem.

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03"
```

Code to show the popup:

```
val materialDateBuilder: MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> =  MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        materialDateBuilder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme)
        materialDateBuilder.setTitleText("")
        val materialDatePicker: MaterialDatePicker<*> = materialDateBuilder.build()
        materialDatePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER")
```

Please let me know if someone has already faced such problem and fixed it.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reverting on my Question. So those, who are facing this problem, please check what parent `Activity` you are extending. In my case, I was extending `FragmentActivity`, but with Material design we need to extend `AppCompatActivity`. It will resolve above design issue.

Comment: I use AppCompatActivity and the problem still persists... maybe that is not the real cause?